# How to use array values as substitutes for names of other arrays

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting

I am still new to Bash and can only use Bash 3 at work.  I'm trying to build a process that will allow me to connect to all of our databases (`DEV`/`TEST`/`PROD`).

I have a file named environments.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
## 0 = Password, 1 = HOST, 2 = SERVICENAME

## List of all Environments
ENV[0]=DEV
ENV[1]=TEST
ENV[2]=PROD

## Dev Env Details
DEV[0]=SU_DBA_201503
DEV[1]=xxxxxx-Dev-xx.xxx.xxx.xxx  #<-- I edited this for security purposes
DEV[2]=dev.xxx.xxx 

## Test Env Details
TEST[0]=DBA_PN_0002
TEST[1]=xxxxxx-Test-xx.xxx.xxx.xxx
TEST[2]=test.xxx.xxx

## Prod Env Details
PROD[0]=TM_DB_US7a6a
PROD[1]=xxxxxx-Prod-xx.xxx.xxx.xxx
PROD[2]=prod.xxx.xxx
```

So essentially, my goal is to loop through all environments (`DEV`, `TEST`, `PROD`) and access each array's attributes to build a connection string.

At this point I have a new file (for testing purposes, I've callit it `looper.csh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

#Get environments
source ./environments.sh

for env in ${ENV[@]}
do
    echo Current Env $env
    cur_env=$env
    for attr in ${cur_env[@]}
    do
    # Will eventually build connection string but for now, just want to echo
        echo $attr
    done
done
```

But when I run this, it gives me an error on the line:

```
for attr in ${cur_env[@]}
```

I've tried a few different ways to substitute this correctly, but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Any and all guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: _.csh_ with a `#!/bin/bash` hashbang? You may want to check that naming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest indirect variable references:

```
source ./environments.sh

for env in "${ENV[@]}"
do
    cur_env="${env}[@]"
    for attr in "${!cur_env}"
    do
        # whatever
    done
done
```

Note the `!` before the `cur_env` in the for `attr`, it means use the value of the variable named in this var which on the first round will be `DEV[@]`

Comment: I added quotes around the ${!cur_env}, so values can have spaces if desired etc.

Comment: This works perfectly!  Thank you very much for you help.  I'm not familiar with indirect variables so I will look these up.  Thanks again!

Comment: @XrXca:  You shouldn't only quote variables "so values can have spaces".  You should **always** quote variables.  [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/237982)

Comment: Note that associative array keys aren't stored in the order you declare them, so the `for` loop isn't guaranteed to go in `dev`->`test`->`prod` order.  Not sure if this is an issue in this case, just pointing this out.

Comment: @m0dular, there's no associative arrays here, just regular integer-indexed ones. Bash 3 doesn't even support them, and that's what the OP said they're stuck with.

Comment: @ilkkachu Whoops!  I'm so used to `array+=()` syntax I totally missed that.  Thanks for pointing this out.